# PHP Error: Mysqli_real_query() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given (line 6) + mysqli_use_result() expects exactly 1 parameter, 3 given (line 7)

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page from a website that I took over a few years back. I am a novice on php and are more into Wordpress. Now the page is starting having problems and I get the above errors in the given lines.
This is the code:

```
1. $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "vrvtnl_data", "eric") or die 
   ("fout1"); 
2. //mysqli_select_db("vrvtnl_data",$db) or die ("fout2"); 
3. function test($nummer,$week){ 
4. $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `vakantie` WHERE `tandarts` =' . 
5. $nummer . ''; 
6. $result = mysqli_real_query($sql); 
7. $test = mysqli_use_result($result, 0, "". $week .""); 
8. return $test; }
```

Can somebody help me, as said I am a novice with php, so detailed help ia appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the error message?  Did you look up the documentation for the functions you're using?  What wasn't clear?

Comment: Your function behaves exactly like `mysql_real_escape_string`. If you typed in the error message within Google you would 100% found more than 10 solutions. You did a very good research.

Answer (score 2):

You passing only one parameter (query), but you must pass two parameters (connection link and query).

> ***bool mysqli_real_query ( mysqli $link , string $query )***
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - link
>
> Procedural style only: A link identifier returned by mysqli_connect()
>   or mysqli_init()
>
> - query
>
> The query, as a string.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-query.php

But in your situation you need `mysqli_query`.

Your code should look like:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "vrvtnl_data", "eric") or die ("fout1"); 

function test($nummer, $week) {
    global $db;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `vakantie` WHERE `tandarts` = '$nummer'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql); 
    return $result ? mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) : []; 
}
```

Comment: Thnx Neodan, for your complete answer. If i implement your code, the last line gives this warning: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: @Fastmarky sorry for bad previos answer. I updated my answer